# Match between two tables where field is substring of the other

Tags: mysql

Hi (sorry for the poor title),

I have two tables in a MySQL DB, lets call them `CarMake` and `CarModel`. Both tables have two fields, `ID:int(11)` and `Description:varchar(100)`. For example:

```
       CarMake                     CarModel
ID          Description    | ID          Description
-----------------------------------------------------
123456      Honda          | 12345678    Accord
234567      Toyota         | 12345665    Civic
369258      Lexus          | 23456789    Prius
```

Where each car model shares the same first 6 digits of the ID of its Make. In this example, both Accord and Civic share the first 6 digits of the ID with Honda, therefore they are Honda models.

Now, what I want to do is select all rows from CarMake that **do not** have a record in CarModel where the first 6 digits of the ID match. In this example, my query should return the Lexus row from CarMake, as it does not have a matching row in CarModel.

Nothing I have tried so far has really come close to achieving what I want, so I am posting it here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Solved with help from zerkms**

```
SELECT * FROM CarMake
LEFT JOIN CarModel 
ON CarModel.ID LIKE CONCAT(CarMake.ID, '%')
WHERE CarModel.ID IS NULL;
```

Follow up questions:

- This solution takes a very long time to run, is there any way to improve efficiency?
- What would be the best way to delete the records returned by that query? Is there some way I can combine that into the query itself?

Comment: That's easy 1. `LEFT JOIN` 2. `LIKE` 3. `WHERE ... IS NULL`. Now - your turn.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot zerkms! I'll post the solution in an edit. It does take quite a long time to run though, are there any suggestions to improve the speed? Would indexing be useful here?

Comment: Also, what would be the best way to delete the records returned by that query? Is there some way I can combine that into the query itself?

Comment: I'd be tempted to split `CarModel.ID` across two columns: the first containing the six digit prefix FK referencing `CarMake.ID`; and the second containing the remainder / two digit suffix.

Comment: ... but even if you don't split - it makes sense to cover it with index. "This solution takes a very long time to run, is there any way to improve efficiency" --- show explain. "What would be the best way to delete the records returned by that query" --- just delete with double nested subqueries

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the fields. "just delete with double nested subqueries" - sorry zerkms could you please give me an example of how I would achieve that? I'm still fairly beginner when it comes to SQL.

Comment: I tried 
`DELETE FROM CarMake WHERE CarMake.ID IN ( SELECT CarMake.ID FROM CarMake LEFT JOIN CarModel ON CarModel.ID LIKE CONCAT(CarMake.ID, '%') WHERE CarModel.ID IS NULL);` but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Try just to delete it immediatly: `DELETE CarMake FROM CarMake
LEFT JOIN CarModel ON CarModel.ID LIKE CONCAT(CarMake.ID, '%') WHERE CarModel.ID IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks @7alhashmi that worked. Takes forever to execute on two tables with ~5000 rows though (around a minute).